# Error with special characters in site column names referenced by a calculated column

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, site-column

I have a site column *Construction - Complete Date* which is used by my calculated column *Construction - Is Complete?*.  Whenever a date is entered for the *Construction - Complete Date* then *Construction - Is Complete?* should be equal to "Yes" otherwise it is "No".

My calculated column formula reads as below:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Construction - Complete Date]),"No","Yes")
```

However, when I save the calculated column and check my existing rows the calculation is not being done correctly.  When I go back to my calculated column the formula has changed to this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(#NAME?-#NAME?),"No","Yes")
```

I've read in this [blog article](http://geekswithblogs.net/kjones/archive/2011/05/08/145240.aspx) that it is a problem for site columns but not for list columns and that the solution is to change the name and remove the "-".  However, I need to keep it as a site column because it is used by multiple content types and I use the "-" convention to group common fields that are all for the same list entry.  Is there an alternative option where I could keep the name and get the calculated column to work?

Comment: Strangely, this works in SP 2013. I will try to reproduce the issue on SP 2010. Is "Construction - Complete Date" column of type DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

The Construction - Complete Date is the Name of your column, but if you look closely, you'll find that SharePoint changes that '-' into a space. Hover over the column in the library/list settings under Column, and you'll find the internal name of the SharePoint column, and use that.

Comment: I tried change the "-" to a space (3 spaces total) but that didn't work ("Construction   Complete Date").  I got the error "The formula refers to a column that does not exist."  Also, when hovering over the column in the settings I didn't see the internal name.

Comment: Try with another space between Construction and Complete. Remember it's "Construction - Complete Date" so removing the "-" out and replacing it with a space makes it "Construction---Complete Date" (three spaces between Construction and Complete.

Comment: That's what I did.  In my comment I entered 3 spaces but SharePoint Overflow reduced it to 1.

Comment: Well try hovering over the column link in the list settings and it will show a URL with the Internal Column name in its parameters. Use that and consider %20 is a space

Comment: I tried using the internal name (which includes '_x0020' and other weird characters) but it did not recognize it.  BTW, I need to change this at the content type level and not at the list level so the internal name at the list settings level might not be the same.

Comment: '_x0020' is a space.

Comment: Safety%20Authority%20Approval this is a part of a url name of one SharePoint site. the "%20" bit is the space. SharePoint uses %20 to transform a space into characters. So "Construction - Complete Date" in this instance you have 7 characters, not 3.